# Randomly grouped objects in one line

Tags: node-editor, geometry-nodes

I want to create a random grouped number of objects (from collection) along a straight line. Unfortunately I can't do the grouping so that there are the same objects next to each other.

Currently:

[image]

Geometry Nodes:
[image]

Expected result:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You've plugged your random integer into the 'Pick Instance' Boolean input of *Instance on Points*, which is a switch to determine whether the entire collection is instanced on each point, or items selected from the collection are instanced on each point. Without further instruction, 'Pick Instance' will cycle through the instances in the collection.

You need your random integer to select *which* items are instanced:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Below is a technique i use to map from a bunch of groups to individual elements. The problem is that each group has a different size and finding the start and end of each group in the final array would normally require a binary search.

[image]

The key idea is to avoid the search by creating a grid first, where each row has enough entries for the largest group. The group index and item index in the grid can be computed with simple arithmetic and captured as attributes. Then delete row entries that exceed the respective group size. This works very well as long as the group size doesn't become too extreme (generates N * M temporary points, where N is the number of groups and M the max. number of group elements).

First determine the size of each group (capture isn't strictly necessary). Note the *Instance* domain.
[image]

Then make a "grid" with enough points per row for the largest group. It's not actually a grid, i'm just conceptually dividing points into rows and columns.
[image]

Now i can compute the index of the row and column, which will become the group index and item index within its group, respectively. Capturing these is necessary because we will delete elements after this (and it also converts the float division result to integer, which is nice). I use named attributes here only because that makes debugging easier with the spreadsheet, capturing unnamed attributes would work just as well.
[image]

And finally delete the extra points in groups that smaller than the max.
[image]

Now you have a list of points with a group and item index, which you can array in a line, and use the `group_index` to select the instance.
[image]